# how to execute python terminal from vs code to cmd or other

Tags: python, cmd, execute

I learn about python, so I run python code in visual studio code on windows by creating a folder consisting of files `main.py` and `settings.json`.

The results in the terminal have no errors, but I am confused about execute the results to cmd or other files to be given to the user without seeing my code.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal, navigate to the same folder your python file is located, and enter

```
python main.py
```

Or, if you're not going to navigate to the folder, you can include the entire path like this

```
python C:/Users/User/Desktop/Folder/main.py
```

Comment: Or you could do it properly, and use, `"F:\ull\Path To\python.exe" "P:\ath To\main.py"`, which would mean you didn't have to mess with, or rely upon, environment variables etc, _(in this case, at least `%PATHEXT%` and `%Path%`)_.